# Asyncio + Aiohttp Making HTTP Requests Slower

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a 3Mil links on CSV file and I'm using pandas, Asyncio, Aiohttp and pypeln to send requests and retrieve json data. But the process is fast at first then after 5000 requests it become slow and start sending requests one by one. Any idea why? Am I using Asyncio incorrectly?

My code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import pandas as pd
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
import os
import time
import queue
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector, client_exceptions, ClientTimeout
import pypeln as pl

json_results = []
json_results_error = []

data = pd.read_csv('Location_links1.csv', encoding='utf8')
limit = 1000
urls = (url for url in data['Link'])

async def main():
    async with ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(limit=0)) as session:
        async def fetch(url):
            
            try:
                    async with session.get(url) as response:
                            results = await response.json()
                            print("{}: done".format(response.url))
                            try:
                                answer = results["results"][0]["locations"]
                                output = {
                                    "Link": url,
                                    "Provided location": results["results"][0][
                                        "providedLocation"
                                    ].get("location"),
                                    "City": answer[0].get("adminArea5"),
                                    "State": answer[0].get("adminArea3"),
                                    "Country": answer[0].get("adminArea1")
                                }

                                json_results.append(output)
                            except (IndexError, JSONDecodeError, TypeError):
                                output = {
                                    "Link": url,
                                    "City": None,
                                    "State": None,
                                    "Country": None
                                }
                                json_results.append(output)
                            pd.DataFrame(json_results).to_csv("{}_bak".format("temp_location1.csv"))
            except (aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError, aiohttp.ClientResponseError,aiohttp.ClientConnectorError) as s:
                print("Oops, the server connection was dropped on ")
                output = {"Link": url,
                          "City": None,
                          "State": None,
                          "Country": None
                          }
                json_results_error.append(output)
                pd.DataFrame(json_results_error).to_csv("{}_bak".format("temp_location_error1.csv"))
                    

        await pl.task.each(
            fetch,
            urls,
            workers=limit,
        )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Does the endpoint accept that many requests??

Comment: Yes, it does accept many requests.

Comment: My advice is to move all CPU bound operations to other Processes and writing files operations to other Threads. I also had situation when aiohttp stops receiving/sending data but no errors ... , it happened due to the fact that loop was busy with some heavy computations. Check `run_in_executor` and `to_thread` in Python Docs